# Is this a global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Are the below variables global variables?

```
var a = 10, b = 20;
c = 30;
```

Any variable without "var" is global. so is variable "b" also a global variable?

Answer (score 4):

No; the `var` statement can declare multiple variables in a comma-separated list.

Note that the statement

```
var a = 1, b = c = 3;
```

will create `c` as a global variable (since it isn't being declared).

Answer (score 1):

The `c` is definitely global; you can test it with `console.log(window.c === 30)`

The other two are only global if the `var` declaration is not inside a function.

Keep in mind that in *strict mode*, the assignment to a variable that was not declared will result in a *ReferenceError*.

Comment: In the code below, what is variable "c", global or local?                             function a() { c = 30; } Though there is no var keyword, os it is supposed to be global. but it cannot be accessed from outside the function

Comment: @NikhilPai: In the code in your comment, `c` is global because there's no `var` ***unless*** that function is inside another function that had declared `var c`. If you can't access it outside, then there's some other issue.

Comment: c will be defined in this case, you just need to run the function first. When the function executes, it will look for the variable c in the function's scope. There is none, so it will look in the higher level scope, the global context in this case.

Comment: @NikhilPai: You didn't invoke `a()`, so the code never runs, and therefore never creates `a`. http://jsfiddle.net/dwLubw6x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first statement isn't in global scope, then no- neither `a` nor `b` are global variables because you're defining a list of vars in the first statement. However, if you did the following:

```
c = 30, d = 90;
```

you would have defined both `c` and `d` as global variables, regardless of the scope in which you defined them.

Answer (score 0):

"Any variable without 'var' is global" is not necessarily true. `var` simply declares a variable in the current scope. The default scope (assuming you are running this JS in a browser and not something like node.js) is the `window` object.

Essentially, yes, all three of those variables are global.

Further reading on what I'm referring to regarding scope and the `var`keyword: [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures).

The above is all assuming you are not running in strict mode/`"use strict"`; - if you are in strict mode, `c` will throw a ReferenceError as you have not declared it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

"b" is not considered a global variable, you can declare more than one variable, as long as the are divided by commas. "c" is the only global variable in that statement. You cannot declare both a global and local variable in the same line separated by commas.

```
a = 10, b = 5;
```

global declaration

```
var a = 10, b = 5;
```

local declaration

Additionally, you can declare them like this:

```
var a = 10, b = 5;
```

Outside all other functions, and it will be global.

Answer (score 0):

var a = 10, b = 20;
c = 30;

Yes off course variable c is global here. If you define a variable without "var " keyword in any scope, the variable is treated as global as it becomes part of global scope.

for var a and b:

if its declared inside a function, they are treated as local variables(as they will be part of local scope/function scope). 
if they are declared and not part of any functions, then they are treated as global variables(as they are added into global scope).